# C++ List all combinations of x amount of numbers (must be bigger than 0) that adds up to y?

Tags: c++

How do we list all combinations of x amount of numbers that adds up to y? Those numbers must be bigger than 0.

Note: 0 is not accepted. We can only add x amount of positive numbers that adds up to y.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// Prototype.
bool Function( unsigned int in_x, unsigned int in_y );

int main() {
    // Declarations.
    unsigned int x = 0;
    unsigned int y = 0;

    // Ask for x.
    std::cout << "\nEnter x:\n";
    std::cin >> x;

    // Ask for y.
    std::cout << "\nEnter y:\n";
    std::cin >> y;

    // Begin.
    Function( x, y );

    // Notify and stop.
    std::cout << "\nDone!\n";
    std::cin.ignore();
    ::getchar();

    // Exit with success.
    return 0;
};

bool Function( unsigned int in_x, unsigned int in_y ) {
    // Error handler.
    if( in_x == 0 ) {
        return false; }

    // Generate and list...
    // *Note: 0 is not accepted. We can only add x amount of positive numbers that adds up to y.
    // How do we do it?

    return false;
};
```

Examples of inputs and outputs:

EXAMPLE #1:

```
Enter x:
3

Enter y:
5

//          x               |   y
0>      3   +   1   +   1   =   5
1>      2   +   2   +   1   =   5
Count = 2

Done!
```

EXAMPLE #2:

```
Enter x:
2

Enter y:
5

//          x       |   y
0>      3   +   2   =   5
1>      4   +   1   =   5
Count = 2

Done!
```

x is 2. Which means, our function could only generate two positive numbers that adds up to y, which is 5.

Comment: @RobertWish: What do you mean by ["whole numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number)? I guess you mean only non-negative whole numbers or natural numbers. Also, have you tried anything? There is at least one simple approach that has a bad runtime but prints all tuples.

Comment: @Zeta Whoops, sorry. Yes I mean only positive numbers.

Comment: @Zeta. I stand corrected. I didn't mean whole numbers. I meant any numbers that are bigger than 0! Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: For anyone unclear on OPs question. He'd like to find out the number of ways to write some positive integer n as the sum of k positive integers where k is fixed.

OP you'll need to do some reading and researching of your own here so you can provide us with some ideas of your own. I suggest you read up on...

Partitions
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: Interesting, I was going to ask for a link to an algorithm that is close to what I am about to do here. Thanks.

Comment: As a side note. Project Euler ( http://projecteuler.net/ ) is packed full of problems like this so if you're going to be doing a few like these, you might want to look there. The problems increase in difficulty such that by the time you get to something like the question you asked, you'd have used partitions and memoization before so it will be a lot more familiar.